# What is the meaning of power delivered by the battery after $t$ seconds?

Tags: energy, power, batteries

I don't get it when a question asks power delivered by a battery after t seconds, are they talking about the total energy delivered by the battery in time t seconds divided by the time, or are they asking about the instantaneous power deliver at time t, and if whichever is true how do we calculate it

Comment: Please add some context to the question. Some additional details regarding the question, maybe.

Comment: @SchrodingersCat Pulkit is asking for general advice here. He's not asking for help with a specific question.

Comment: @PM2Ring Actually, these questions are very ambiguous in general. Asking for advice for a general situation will not be helpful in such a case. I hope the OP did not conjure this question all by himself and must have seen it in some form somewhere. Any added context (regarding anything else) might help to understand what kind of interpretation the question can bring about.

Comment: @SchrodingersCat *"Actually, these questions are very ambiguous in general"*. Really? Good textbooks and homework & exam questions try to avoid such ambiguous language. Of course, it can be difficult to totally eliminate all ambiguity, and you need to consider the context. It also helps if you're familiar with the language style of the question writer.

Comment: (cont) Sometimes, you have to take a guess at what's the most likely interpretation based on what you're expected to know at your current stage of education. Eg, if you're just starting mechanics, you can assume that you can ignore friction, and that you can use simple algebra to solve the problem, and you don't need to use calculus.

Answer (score 1):

Typically in such questions, the 1st interpretation is intended, that is, they want you to calculate the total energy delivered by the battery up to time $t$, divided by $t$. The instantaneous power at time $t$ (usually) isn't as important, and if they *do* want you to calculate it you *should* be able to tell that from the context.

IMHO, good textbooks (and exam papers) avoid such ambiguous language...